# PySpark writing to Postgres loses time zone

Tags: python, postgresql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I create a Spark (v3.0.2) dataframe and write it to a new PostgreSQL table like this:

```
cols = ['c1','c2']
d_aware = datetime.datetime.now().astimezone()

# Python docs defining aware object
assert d_aware.tzinfo is not None
assert d_aware.tzinfo.utcoffset(d_aware) is not None

data = [('a', d_aware)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*cols)

df.write.format('jdbc') \
  .mode('append') \
  .option('url', 'jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb?user=user&password=pass') \
  .option('dbtable', 'test_timestamp') \
  .option('driver', 'org.postgresql.Driver') \
  .save()
```

Then I go to `psql` and say `\d test_timestamp` I get the following table:

```
                    Table "public.test_timestamp"
 Column |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 c1     | text                        |           |          | 
 c2     | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
```

When I look at the inserted value for c2, the time is my local machine time (machine is NOT UTC time zone).

2 Questions:

1. How come the c2 column type is `timestamp without time zone` and not `timestamptz`?
2. Why didn't the time value get converted to UTC time as stated in Spark documentation before getting saved to dataframe and then to Postgres? Or is Spark, Postgres server and psql all working together and showing me time in my local timezone? But if that's the case, then the column type must have been `timestamptz`, right?